# add new rows in a table using ajax success

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have jquery Ajax function like this:

```
    $("#Prices").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        autoResize: true, buttons: {
            "OK": function () {                     




            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Home/RecordingRates",
            data: {
                currencyID: $("#currencyId").val()                 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "success") {                   
                  // poulate a table

                }
                else {
                    jQuery("#dialog-user-login").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                    jQuery("#dialog-user-login").dialog("open");
                }
               }
            }); 
           }
        }
        ,
        open: function () {
           $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').focus();
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button:contains("OK")').addClass('customokbutton');
        }
    });
```

I want to populate a table from the data returned by RecordingRates controller action which is like this:

```
   public JsonResult RecordingRates(int currencyId) {
            string result = "success";
            using (IDefaultRateChartManager defaultRateChartManager = new ManagerFactory().GetDefaultRateChartManager()) {
                List<DefaultRateChart> defaultRateCharts = defaultRateChartManager.GetAll().Where(rc => rc.Currency.Id == currencyId && (!rc.NumberPrefix.StartsWith("#") || rc.NumberPrefix.StartsWith("Default")) && rc.AccountCredit == "Credit").ToList();
                ViewBag.defaultRateCharts = defaultRateCharts;
            }
            return Json(result);
        }
```

and table is like this:

```
 <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        head 1
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        head 2
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
```

I want to add a new row against the items in viewbag.defaultRateCharts

Please suggest me how to change ajax call, controller action and html.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display your data in a HTML Table.

I think you should take a look at a Jquery Templating library.

I personnaly use [handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

The data binding part is very simple, it looks like

```
success: function (data) {
                    var result = yourTemplate(data);
                    $("#yourHTMLTableContainer").appendTo(result);
                }

<script id="YourHandleBarTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#d}}
    <tr class="xxx" onclick="GetDetails('{{YourID}}')">
        <td>{{PropertyToDisplayInHead1}}</td>
        <td>{{PropertyToDisplayInHead2}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/d}}
</script>
```

and in my DOM Load, I compile the template, looks like this

```
YourTemplate = null; 
$(document).ready(function () {
    YourTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#YourHandleBarTemplate").html());
});
```

edit: I realise I use the beta version of the library, my project is about 1 year old and I didn't rework on it, but I'm pretty sure the pattern will be just about the same with the new version or another similar templating library.